# Qtcreator ругается на рабочий проект

Tags: qtcreator

Собственно говоря сабж.

Проект: https://github.com/valualit/QT_OpenGL_lesson1

Сама проблема: [image: Сама проблема]

Комплект: [image: Комплект]

---

Если запустить от рута, то всё работает как нужно.

Comment: уж установлен русский креатор и всё равно читать не умеем, make завершился успешно, о чём это говорит? А красные точки это статический анализатор даёт, надо его отключить.

Comment: А с автодополнением как быть?

Comment: автодополнение и стат. анализатор разные вещи, хотя последние креаторы не смотрел

Comment: Я понимаю, что это разные вещи, но в автодополнение нет тех функций на которые ругается анализатор.

У меня 2 qtcreator стоят, один из них с сайта qt в нём тот раз таки и наблюдается данная проблема. В Qtcreator из репозитория наблюдается немного другая проблема: https://i.imgur.com/UmI2jJn.png
Разумеется и автодополнение не работает для того на что ругается анализатор...

Comment: `About plugins/C++/Clang...` - попробуйте выключить это всё

Comment: Да, это убирает "ошибки", но в автокомпиле до сих нет функций, на которые ругался анализатор.